# having difficulty while creating crystal report in vb.net with ms-access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report, I dont know anything about it, but I need to create a crystal report which will show and save the following fields from the following table:

database Disha

```
table_client_master
=====================
sr.no || Client_name

table_hotelBook fields
=====================================
From || to || room || nights || extraper || ouramount
```

Here client_master and hotelbook contain srno, which will be the same username as is stored in client_master and the information of booking in hotelBook.

Here, when the user clicks on the mail button, it will generate and save a report automatically in a folder. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to start study from Basic.

PLease follow below [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28899/Crystal-Report-with-DataSet-and-DataTable-using-C). There is so many link available on for crystal report study.